# Get and apple touch icon from external site using php

Tags: php

Im trying to get the url of the apple touch icon image using php but i am not successful. I found this on S.O. using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but this doesnt work either:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$img = $html->find('img[rel=apple-touch-icon]');
echo $img->href;
```

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? I was thinking I could use file_get_contents() but I am not sure how to approach that.

Comment: Did you included that library in your application? Don't expect it to work if you don't include it..

Comment: Yea I did. It was the first thing I did lol. Tried include, require and ...once.

Comment: if you are searching for image then use    `echo $img->src;`    if you are using   `img`    tag

Comment: interested... is there also a way to get `apple-touch-icon` using curl?